# If we add an Item to Custom SPList .It will not view by any other...likewise we cannot view their item which was added by them...-SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

If we add an Item to Custom SPList .It will not view by any other(they also have permission to access the SPList)...likewise we cannot view their item which was added by them...

Answer (score 0):

May be this list using the stop inheriting property = false. That's y the user created item only displaying for the current user.

Answer (score 0):

Two List Settings to check:

1. Versioning settings: If Content Approval is Yes, check the Draft Item Security. If users are adding items to a version enabled list, but are not marking those items as approved, then those items will not be visible to all other users.
2. Advanced settings: If Item-level Permissions is Read items that were created by the user, then only the author, list owners, and site collection administrators will be able to view an item.